# Are local variables necessary?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, calling-convention

My understanding is the C calling convention places arguments on the stack prior to calling a function. These arguments could be accessed within the function through explicit stack parameters using `EBP` as a reference such as `[EBP + 8]` or `[EBP + 12]`.

My question is if it could be accessed this way, why are local variables necessary? - couldn't a function just work with the arguments directly? Is it just for cases where the function has no parameters, but still initializes local variables for internal use?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Local variables are usually also put onto the stack, so that there is no real difference. Or do you mean to ask "why load things into CPU registers instead of accessing them from the stack (or other memory areas) every time?"

Comment: A function can indeed modify its parameters, and it does it precisely as you say. But what if a function wants to store *additional* data that isn't passed as a parameter? Then it needs a local variable. Are you asking in the context of compiled C code, or when you're manually writing assembly? In the latter case, there is really no such thing as a "local variable"—just space allocated on the stack or elsewhere in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite often, functions need to remember more data than just the parameters. For example, consider this function counting the number of set bits in its argument:

```
int popcount(int k)
{
    int count = 0;

    while (k != 0) {
        k &= k - 1;
        count++;
    }

    return (count);
}
```

In addition to the parameter, we also need to remember how many bits we saw. Thus, a local variable is required.